# Can I change the getServerSideProps fetch url by onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to change the fetch url, but I can't find an answer. For example, I want to change my `let page` and refresh `getServerSideProps` for rerendering all News by clicking on the button.

Can  I do it or do I need another alternative way?

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { NewsArticle, NewsResponse } from "@/modules/NewsArticles";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import NewsArticleGrid from "@/components/NewsArticleGrid";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

interface BreakingNewsPageProps {
  newsArticles: NewsArticle[];
}

let page =
  "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2023-05-03&to=2023-05-03&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<BreakingNewsPageProps> = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(page + process.env.NEWS_API_KEY);
  const newsResponse: NewsResponse = await response.json();
  return {
    props: { newsArticles: newsResponse.articles },
  };
};

export default function BreakingNewsPage({ newsArticles }: BreakingNewsPageProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Breaking news </title>
      </Head>
      <main>
        <h1>Breaking News</h1>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            page =
              "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2023-04-03&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=";
            console.log(page);
            router.push(router.asPath);
          }}
        >
          Change url
        </Button>
        <NewsArticleGrid articles={newsArticles} />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `page` variable you use in `getServerSideProps` only exists on the server. It will not be accessible on the browser, where your button click handler runs.

You could refresh with a query string that gets sent to `getServerSideProps`. Find below a similar example that fetches a new post on click:

```js
// pages/index.js

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          router.push({
            href: router.pathname,
            query: { page: Math.round(Math.random() * 10) },
          });
        }}
      >
        Fetch another random post
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

const defaultPage = 1;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + (context.query.page || defaultPage));
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { post: data },
  };
};
```

I used the `jsonplaceholder` API to have it work for anyone easily after copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js 13 app page

```
// page.jsx
async function getUsers(page) {
    const res = await fetch(
        `
    https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?page=${page}&per_page=3`,
        {
            headers: {
                "Primary-Token": "",
            },
        }
    );
    return res.json();
}

export default async function Home({ searchParams }) {
    let page = searchParams.page !== undefined ? Number(searchParams.page) : 1;

    const data = await getUsers(page);

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            {data.map((el) => {
                return <Link href={`/${el.id}`}>go to {el.name}</Link>;
            })}
            <Button page={page} />
        </main>
    );
}
```

And Button client-side page

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Button({ page }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                router.push(`?page=${(page += 1)}`);
            }}>
            click me
        </button>
    );
}
```